# Copying a linked list and returning a pointer to the new list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

My current struct is:

```
typedef char AirportCode[4];
typedef struct node{
  AirportCode airport;
  struct node *next;
}Node;
```

My idea for how the function should start is this:

```
Node *copy(Node *list) {
int count = 0;
  while (list != NULL){
   count++;
   list = list->next;
}
}
```

Now we know how long the original list is, but the reason why I am so stumped is because I have no idea how to seperatly allocate the memory for each individual node that we have to copy to the second list.

Comment: Your question is not clear..and please upload complete code about list and other things!

Comment: looks like an infinite loop `while (list != NULL) count++;` you probably meant `for (; list != NULL; list = list->next) count++;`

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to "need help allocating memory in C to copy a linked list" or something

Comment: I fixed my while loop ClapTrap. I think that should do the same as the for loop you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate a new node with malloc:

```
Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Then you can change stuff inside your new Node with

```
newNode->airport = <blah blah blah>
newNode->next = <other node, etc etc>
```

It might be easier to clone with recursion rather than loop, if you use a loop, unless you like to do a lot of pointer manipulation and keep track of many nodes at a time (similar to [reversing a linked list in place](http://www.teamten.com/lawrence/writings/reverse_a_linked_list.html)), use a stack.

So it would be something like this:

```
Node* cloneList(Node* head){
    if (!head)
        return NULL;//done
    Node* n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->airport = head->airport;
    n->next = cloneList(head->next);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: How would I do that with a linked list of undetermined length inside some sort of loop?

Comment: Elegant solution but for long lists this will use up a lot of stack space and might evenually overflow.

Comment: @MichaelWalz that's true, but with our 4 GB memory these days and the kind of toy application that the OP seems to be trying to make, I doubt it'll happen. I was mainly worried that the OP would get lost trying to figure out how the loop works with all the pointer references and stuff

Comment: @stakSmashr: but the  stack size is limited (typically 1 Mb or so) even if your computer has 4Gb of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but this should do the job :

```
Node *copy(Node *list) {
  int count = 0;
  Node *previous = NULL ;
  Node *firstnode = NULL ;

  while (list != NULL){
   Node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node)) ;

   if (firstnode == NULL)
     firstnode = newnode ;

   memcopy(newnode, list, sizeof(Node)) ;
   newnode->next = NULL ;

   if (previous != NULL)
     previous->next = newnode ;

   previous = newnode ;
   count++;
   list = list->next;
  }

  return firstnode ;
}
```

Comment: In the memcpy(newnode, list) part, how does the compiler know what part of the list you are copying to newnode?

Comment: Sorry, I juste edited the answer, it should read `memcopy(newnode, list, sizeof(Node)) ;`.