# Copying Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote a function that copies a linked list. Unfortunately it doesn't copy the list completely.

```
Node *copy(Node *list)
{
    Node *copy2;
    while(list != NULL) {
        copy2 = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        memcpy(copy2,list,sizeof(Node));
        list = list->next;
        if(list != NULL) {
            copy2->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            copy2 = copy2->next;
        }
    }
    return copy2;
}
```

Comment: You do not allocate memory for `copy2` before `memcpy`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Tried it same result. The first node doesn't get copied for some reason.

Comment: You are leaking memory by doing `copy2->next=malloc(sizeof(Node));` followed by `copy2=copy2->next` and  `copy2=malloc(sizeof(Node));` Your first allocation is leaked, you cant free it, till you terminate the process

Comment: Always remember to do sanity checks on what `malloc` has returned. Ex: `copy2 = malloc(sizeof(Node));` `if (copy2 == NULL) printf("malloc failed");`

Comment: So do I only need to do malloc once for copy2? If i try to store copy2->copy2->next without using copy2->next = malloc(sizeof(Node)); it gives me a segmentation error.

Comment: No, you must allocte each node, but you need to keep the pointer to your 1st node - the list head.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217990/copying-a-linked-list-and-returning-a-pointer-to-the-new-list/22218364#22218364)

Comment: @MichaelWalz if it is, the answer by ARLabs here is far better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives you only the last element and it also has lots of memory leaks.

1. You don't need two malloc for each element.
2. You need to keep both reference at the head of the list and at the current copied element
3. You need to keep the pointer to reference to change the pointer inside the previous node.

Try this.

```
Node *copy(Node *list)
{
    Node *newList = NULL;
    Node **newIt = &newList;
    while(list!=NULL)
    {
        *newIt = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        memcpy(*newIt,list,sizeof(Node));

        list = list->next;
        newIt = &((*newIt)->next);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 major bugs here:

1. You don't store the head of the copied list. Anywhere. And when you return `copy2` you return a pointer to the last element of the list and forever lose the reference to the list head.
2. `copy2` isn't dynamically allocated and will be deallocated when your function exits. This will likely lead to a segmentation fault if you fix issue 1.

Comment: "copy2 isn't dynamically allocated and will be deallocated whe your function exits." ... `malloc` is dynamic allocation, malloced memory is  freed by a call to `free` or when the process exits/killed

Comment: `copy2=malloc(sizeof(Node));` , is dynamic allocation

Comment: @Deepthought question was updated since it was first asked (first malloc wasn't there initially).

Comment: The question was edited. The original code snippet didn't allocate the 1st element

Answer (score 0):

Here is C++ code for coping linked list to another linked list

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
};

Node* copy(Node* list) {
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;

    Node* result = new Node;
    result->value = list->value;
    result->next = copy(list->next);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: OP is using `C` not `C++`

Comment: @immortal: There is no new api in C

Comment: @Rahul I don't quite understand your statement, C pre-dates C++, and C++ is mostly backward compatible with C. Still, compiling C with a C++ compiler doest make it C++

Comment: @immortal:In C you need malloc for memory allocation while in C++ there is new for creating new object with memory allocation

Comment: I think that the solution is good, can be easily "ported" to plain C, but in no real case you should opt for a recursive solution when an iterative one is available, as in this case.